# Creating histogram on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to create a graph on R but keep getting this error...

> Error in inherits(mapping, "uneval") : object 'EI.TOT' not found

I have put in this command:

```
hist.1 <- ggplot(data, EI.TOT) + theme(legend.position = "none") + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white") + labs(x="EI.TOT", y = "Density")
```

EI.TOT is the header of one of my columns.  I have run a regression using these values but when I want to create a histogram is says that this column is not found.

Comment: try ..hist.1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=EI.TOT))...

Answer (score 2):

Your trouble is that you dont specify your aes correctly. Try this code, let me know if it does not work on your data.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(EI.TOT =rnorm(60))

hist.1 <- ggplot(data=data) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_histogram(aes(EI.TOT),colour="black", fill="white", binwidth = 0.5) +
  labs(x="EI.TOT", y = "Density")


hist.1
```

Change bindwidth to change the breaks in the plot.